# How to make a batch request to get feed from a list of friends?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I can get the feed for a list of users, but by making one call at a time, hence, a LONG delay!

I am trying to make a batch processing, requesting the "feed" from a list of users (friends of a given "user").

My latest trial:
($Fids is an array containing the facebook user_id (ie 123456789012) )

```
$Fb = new Facebook(array('appId'=>FB_API_ID,'secret'=>FB_API_SECRET));
$access_token = $Fb->getAccessToken();
$queries = array();
for ($i=0; $i<$siz; $i++)
    $queries[] = array (    'method' => 'GET',
            'relative_url' => $Fids[$i]['foreignid']
        );
$batch = json_encode($queries); // works up to here
$objs = $Fb->api('/?batch='.$queries, 'POST');
```

I can't get any kind of reply.
Someone has made it??

Answer (score 0):

Can you do a try catch on

```
$objs = $Fb->api('/?batch='.$queries, 'POST');
```

like

```
try{
$objs = $Fb->api('/?batch='.$queries, 'POST');
} catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
  error_log($e);
  $user = null;
}
```

Comment: No luck with that one, sorry.